# Get Leads data from facebook to integrate with CMS?

Tags: php, facebook-marketing-api

I want to retrieve the leads data from the facebook Marketing API and it should synchronize with the client custom CRM. I have gone through the guide given by facebook but I am not sure how to implement and get the result.

Is there a way to set up my code so that my leads data is directly triggered into the client CRM? Without using any third party tool?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/guides/lead-ads/retrieving/v2.8 - see webhooks, in particular.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this through the Marketing API.

There is a full guide here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/guides/lead-ads/